# Adding blank space to pdf using postscript / ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

Can anyone suggest how to extend page size on one side using postscript? I have to put a mark on a heavy bunch of documents. I use postscript for this (as technology that most native to pdfs, obviously as speed is critical for the task).
I am able to put a mark on the document itself, but I have to add a blank field to the right of each page and this is the problem.

This is what is going on (the mark [copy] is added above the pdf)

[image]

This is what has to be (page size extended with blank field on the right):

[image]

This is the content of my mark.ps  file

```
 <<
   /EndPage
   {
     2 eq { pop false }

     {
        gsave   

        7.0 setlinewidth
        70 780 newpath moveto
        70 900 lineto
        120 900 lineto
        120 780 lineto
        66.5 780 lineto 
        stroke
        closepath


        /Helvetica findfont 18 scalefont setfont
        newpath
        100 792.5 moveto
        90 rotate
        (COPY) true charpath fill
        1 setlinewidth stroke
        0 setgray


         grestore
         true
     } ifelse
   } bind
>> setpagedevice
```

This is how it is applied to pdf

```
gs \
-q \
-dBATCH \
-dNOPAUSE \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite  \
-sOutputFile=output.pdf \
-f mark.ps \
input.pdf
```

What I tried :

- Change page size `<< /PageSize [595 1642] >> setpagedevice` - didnt work
- use -g option in gs like this: `-g595x1642`  - also didnt work fine

If someone has relevant suggestions please share!

Comment: You need to use -dDEVIWIDTHPOINTS= to specify the desired media width in points, and -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS= along with -dFIXEDMEDIA. The content of the PDF is drawn at bottom left, so overriding the media size with a larger size will have the effect of increasing the 'margins' at right and top.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work well for me.  These options do crop content if specify smaller size, but specifying larger size does not add anything to pages.

Comment: Please give a complete command line (including the new switches), and an example file then.